# How to remove duplicate entires using the latest time in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Here is the snippet:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                     'start_time':[datetime(2017,7,20),datetime(2017,6,20),datetime(2017,5,20),datetime(2017,4,20),datetime(2017,3,20),datetime(2017,2,20)],
                     'amount': [10,11,12,13,14,15]})
```

Output:

```
      amount start_time uid
     0  10   2017-07-20  1
     1  11   2017-06-20  1
     2  12   2017-05-20  2
     3  13   2017-04-20  2
     4  14   2017-03-20  3
     5  15   2017-02-20  3
```

Desired Output:

```
      amount start_time uid
     0  10   2017-07-20  1
     2  12   2017-05-20  2
     4  14   2017-03-20  3
```

I want to group by `uid` and mind the row with the latest start_time. Basically, I want to remove duplicate uid by only selecting the uid with the latest `start_time`.

I tried `test.groupby(['uid'])['start_time'].max()` but it doesn't work as it only returns back the `uid` and `start_time` column. I need the `amount` column as well.

---

Update: Thanks to @jezrael & @EdChum, you guys always help me out on this forum, thank you so much！

I tested both solutions in terms of execution time on a dataset of 1136 rows and 30 columns:

```
Method A: test.sort_values('start_time', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('uid')
Total execution time: 3.21 ms

Method B: test.loc[test.groupby('uid')['start_time'].idxmax()]
Total execution time: 65.1 ms
```

I guess `groupby` requires more time to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `start_time` with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by `uid`:

```
df = test.sort_values('start_time', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('uid')
print (df)
   amount start_time  uid
0      10 2017-07-20    1
2      12 2017-05-20    2
4      14 2017-03-20    3
```

If need output with ordered `uid`:

```
print (test.sort_values('start_time', ascending=False)
           .drop_duplicates('uid')
           .sort_values('uid'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) to return the index of the latest time and use this to index the original df:

```
In[35]:
test.loc[test.groupby('uid')['start_time'].idxmax()]

Out[35]: 
   amount start_time  uid
0      10 2017-07-20    1
2      12 2017-05-20    2
4      14 2017-03-20    3
```